# What exactly a moderator dashboard looks like?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Congratulations to all the elected Moderators. We are really excited to have you as our community moderators.

I (and hopefully other members too) am really eager to have a glimpse of what the latest Moderator Dashboard and timeline looks like now. I have been through this question: [What's the Moderator Dashboard look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177216/whats-the-moderator-dashboard-look-like)
 but it seems a little outdated (Almost 6 years old).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dashboard shows (mostly very basic looking lists of)

- moderator (in)activity
- flags
- flagged, locked and migrated posts
- some analytics data about the site
- and a bunch of info about moderation tools

Flags appear still similar to what you see in the answers to the referenced question. Not much change there.